# Snowflake Snowpipe to delete and reload into a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowpipe which is loading into a table t1 from S3, and is working absolutely fine.
However now I have to delete and reload the table every time a new file is loaded into S3.

To Address this , My thinking is below

```
1. Create a new table t1_load.
2. create a Snowpipe and load into new table.
3. Create a Stream and load into table t1 and before loading delete the table.
```

**However I am not sure how to delete into table using Stream**

Is it the appropriate approach, Since we have 90 tables it means 90 new load table
or there is a better way.

Basically I am trying to delete and load into snowflake with event driven mythology.
We cannot use task to derive this as it can not be schedule by time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you are using Snowpipe to load many, many files into a table, and if 1 of those files change, you need to truncate that table and reload all of those files?  If so, you likely should be removing Snowpipe altogether and leveraging External Tables with Materialized Views, instead.

If I'm not understanding your scenario, let me know...and I'll delete this answer.  :-)

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html

Comment: This one make sense.. I will try this

Comment: Problem with materialized view is I cannot use sub queries. And in this case I will have to use them. to get the latest date from external table

Comment: The point of external tables is that the files on S3 would all be part of the external table.  So, as files get replaced, removed, or added, the table updates.  I thought that was the scenario you were looking for.

Comment: Here's another question.  Are the files that you are trying to select for a specific date located in separate folders?  Because you could partition your external table and then only reference the latest partition in your materialized view.

Comment: There is no specific date that is the problem

Comment: The file is just getting uploaded into S3 every 3 to 4 days. and is not partitioned by date